# Loop inside loop in queryset in Django template

Tags: django, django-queryset, django-templates

I have queryset like this:

`hello = Hello.objects.all()`

In template I would do like this to get the data:

```
{% for h in hello %}
   {% for i in h.data %} #data is stored like this ['a', 'b', 'c'] -->  I want to access individual componenet, thus I would do:
      {{i}}
   {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

But instead of yielding data as:

```
a 
b
c
```

It yields as `['a', 'b', 'c']`

What's wrong? I have a reason to store data in list. How to access each data seperately. Thanks

**Purpose:**
Colors are stored in data field as: `[black, green, brown]`
Thus I want to achieve:

```
div style="color: black"
div style="color: green"
div style="color: brown"
```

**Edit**
`models.py`
class Hello(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    data = models.CharField(max_length=255)

```
def __str__(self):
    return "%s's decoration photos" % self.user
```

Comment: Could you provide models.py source code?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `Hello` is a model with `data` stored as a CharField, then Django is correct in assuming that you have a string rather than a list.

Try using a model called `Color` which has a ForeignKey to `Hello`. This would be the right way to have a one-to-many relationship between `Hello` and its `Color` objects.

Answer (score -1):

The best way to deal with this would be to write your own django template filter to iterate over the filter.

Very similar to what is given at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/

And getting start is here. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/

Comment: An overkill for such a particular case